# Constructing Arrays Programmatically

Tags: php, arrays, class

I'm writing a PHP web app that uses XML documents from an API. I have to construct many products from the returned XML data.

What I'm doing right now is using xpath and a loop to pull all of the objects into an array of sub-arrays. Then I loop through the array of arrays and pull specific arrays into their own named array. Is there a way to do this with a function or class constructor?

My current code looks something like this:

```
if ( $products_results_list[$key]["sChgDesc"] == "Small Box" ) {
    $small_box = array(
        "ChargeDescID" => $products_results_list[$key]["ChargeDescID"],
        "sChgDesc" => $products_results_list[$key]["sChgDesc"],
        "dcPrice" => $products_results_list[$key]["dcPrice"],
        "dcTax1Rate" => ".0" . $products_results_list[$key]["dcTax1Rate"],
        "dcInStock" => $products_results_list[$key]["dcInStock"],
    );
}
```

After writing the above if statement about 8 times, with many more times needed, I'm thinking there must be a better practice than just writing everything out.

I want to do something like:

```
product_constructor($argument, $product_name) {
  if ( $arguement ) {
    $product_name = array(
        "ChargeDescID" => $products_results_list[$key]["ChargeDescID"],
        "sChgDesc" => $products_results_list[$key]["sChgDesc"],
        "dcPrice" => $products_results_list[$key]["dcPrice"],
        "dcTax1Rate" => ".0" . $products_results_list[$key]["dcTax1Rate"],
        "dcInStock" => $products_results_list[$key]["dcInStock"],
    );
}
```

and then just call the function or constructor as needed like:

```
product_constructor( '$products_results_list[$key]["sChgDesc"] == "Small Box"', '$small_box');
```

I actually tried the above code, but it was throwing errors. Despite working with PHP daily, I still don't know much about constructors, and figured this might be the perfect opportunity to learn how to do this correctly.

I'm not sure if classes are the right choice for this since I'm going to need to pull the products themselves into product package classes later.

Comment: why you dont work with xml as nodes like a SimpleXMLElement?

Comment: You can dynamically create variables with specific names. If `$str = 'myvar'`, then running `$$str = 1` gives you a variable `$myvar` with the value of `1`.

Comment: daremachine, I'm not familiar with SimpleXMLElement, and I already have the xml document parsed using DOMXPath. DJDavid98, I'm not sure how that is applicable here. Would you elaborate on how that would solve the problem?